# How to handle a two dimensional array in spring controller which i am passing through ajax

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, multidimensional-array

My ajax code is as below

```
    function display()
       {
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: "/CRM_Spring/ViewAccessRights/multipleUpdate",

            data:  {getRights: getRights},
            success: function(msg){

                   alert("successfully transfered");

            }

    }); 


  }
```

getRights is my two dimensional array.

However i am not understanding how to handle it in my spring controller.Can anyone please help me regarding the same.

Comment: can you past your server response value of 'msg' in question ? a json or xml ?

Comment: @NaveenRamawat-The request does not go forward.It does'nt print anything

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@RequestParam(value = "getRights", required = true) String[][] RightsArray
```

At the mapping fuction you can get getRights

Comment: -Yes i am using method as POST.

Comment: Check All this 1-Jquery Present in page 2- 2D Array Creation

Answer (score 0):

I think double quota is missing, Please replace

```
data : {getRights: getRights},
```

to

```
data:  {"getRights": getRights},
```

Comment: please use firebug plugin of firefox, It is helpful for identify if any js error occurred.