# Pass bi-dimensional javascript arrays to spring MVC controller wthout ajax

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, multidimensional-array

In javascript I declared a bi-dimensional array:

```
<script>
    var values0=[["001", "2015-09-01", "100", "S"],["002", "2015-09-02", "200", "S"]];

</script>
```

In the form I have an hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hRDSCValues0" name="values"  >
```

This is the code of the submit button:

```
$('#hRDSCValues0').val(values0);

$( "#myModelForm" ).submit();
```

In the spring MVC model I have a field "values":

```
private String[] values;
```

In the controller I receive the two lines of the javascript array in the same dimension:

[image: Image_1]

If in the model I create a bidimensional array:

```
private String[][] values;
```

This is what I have in controller:

[image: Image_2]

How can I pass a bi-dimensional array in javascript to a model of spring MVC controller?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

This is the form:

```
<form:form id="myModelForm" action="/submitMyModel" method="post" commandName="myModel" >
    <input type="hidden" id="hRDSCValues0" name="values"  >
    [...]
```

In the controller there is this request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitMyModel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitMyModel(HttpSession session, 
        @ModelAttribute("myModel")MyModel myModel, 
        Model model) {
    [...]
```

And this is the model:

```
public class MyModel {
    private String[] values;
    [...]

    public String[] getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(String[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

And this is the second version of the model:

```
public class MyModel {
    private String[][] values;
    [...]

    public String[][] getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(String[][] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

Comment: The crucial bit of code is the bit that you don't show, that is how do you extract the arrays from the string passed to the server, is it a spring thing?

Comment: Please post how you are trying to get this two dimensional array from the POST request. Also check if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31267435/1793718) helps.